# Nhibernate many-to-many eager load in one SQL query?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many, criteria, eager-loading

How to force nhibernate to fully load many-to-many data in one sql query.
I have tried this:

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria<Q>("q")
                  .CreateAlias("q.PList", "p", JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
                  .List();
```

But it loads only q.PList, and when I try to access q.PList[0].QList[0].PList[0] NH executes additional select query.

Entities and how I mapped them:

```
public class P
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Q> QList { get; set; }
}
public class Q
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<P> PList{ get; set; }
}
public class PMap : ClassMap<P>
{
    public PMap()
    {
        Table("p");
        Id(t => t.Id);
        HasManyToMany(t => t.QList)
            .Table("q2p").ParentKeyColumn("pId").ChildKeyColumn("qId").Inverse();
    }
}
public class QMap : ClassMap<Q>
{
    public QMap()
    {
        Table("q");
        Id(t => t.Id);
        HasManyToMany(t => t.PList)
            .Table("q2p").ParentKeyColumn("qId").ChildKeyColumn("pId");
    }
}
```

Comment: Generated mappings: http://pastebin.com/1M7UHhfk

Comment: I managed to make it load eagerly by adding .Not.LazyLoad().FetchType.Join() which results in "<bag fetch="join" lazy="false"" change in hbm mapping, but despite of fetch=JOIN it iterates collection and execute SELECT for each item instead of JOIN.  Besides I do not always want such eager behavior and i would like to use query syntax for such eager loading.

Comment: One more thing specifying fetch="subselect" have influence, and now data is fully loaded in 2 queries, why doesn't JOIN work still a mystery for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or use HQL to achieve the same
your query will look as follows

```
var hqlQuery="select p from Q as q inner join fetch q.PList as p";
```

You run the query as follows:

```
 Sesssion.CreateQuery(hqlQuery).List<P>();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you are really trying to do is:

```
var list = session.CreateCriteria<Q>()
                  .SetFetchMode("PList", FetchMode.Join)
                  .List();
```

*Update based on your comment:*

It's cumbersome and usually not worth it to try to fetch a whole graph with many collections using joins. For this particular case, I suggest that you use `batch-size` on the collections and let NH do a batched lazy-loading.

Depending on your code, it's also possible that a HQL query retrieves the data you want better than navigating the object graph.

Comment: this produces the same SQL, and same result as my code. And I need to eager load this, and get rid of lazy loading.

Comment: What's the xml mapping generated by fluent? I just tried it (with NH 3 and an almost default ConfORM mapping) and it generates **both** joins correctly.

Comment: Ahh actually when I try to access q.PList[0].QList[0].PList[0 and not q.PList[0].QList[0]